# Add nomenclature to TeXworks

Tags: miktex, texworks, nomenclature

How do you add nomenclature typesetting tool to TeXworks? I use

```
pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX
```

It produces `.nlo` file but does not put the nomenclature list in the document.

Comment: Thank you. I have found some helpful answers on this section and managed to produce an .nls file. I did this via a batch file but I would prefer a direct way to modify makeindex, or add another typesetting directly to TexWorks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX' entry in TeXworks is MiKTeX-specific, and uses a back-end program called `texify` to run the various parts of the process automatically. If you do `texdoc texify` at the Command Prompt you get some instructions, which include various options. The key one is

```
--mkidx-option=option
Pass option to the index generator.
```

Thus at least in theory what you want to do is add this option to those used by `texify`. However, a few tests soon reveal that this won't help as `texify` doesn't even attempt to run MakeIndex on a short test file such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
Some text

\nomenclature{A}{Something for A}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The `texify` documentation doesn't make it clear, but it seems likely that it only runs MakeIndex if there is an appropriately-named file is created. As one is not by `nomencl`, you have to use an alternative scripting approach such as a batch file, `latexmk`, *etc.*

Comment: What no `arara` recommended before etc.? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[Credit to Joseph Wright for this answer.](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-03/msg01118.html)

MiKTeX allows a limited form of `\write18` to run `makeindex` from within a LaTeX document.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For add new command to typesetting tool, you can do it same as following picture
[image]

In texworks, following step:

1. run pdfTex or pdfLatex or XeTeX or XeLaTex,.. , this step, generate the *.nlo file
2. run bibTex, this step generate the *.bbl file
3. run nomenclute, this step generate *.nls file
4. do twice the step 1