# Nomenclature problem displaying blank lines

Tags: nomenclature

I want to use nomenclature but once I type the nomenclatures it doesn't appears in the document I got only a blank square where normally  should be my nomenclatures

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    c
    c
    c
    c
    c
    c
\end{abstract}

\linenumbers
\section{Introduction}

c
c
c
c
c

\begin{framed}
    \mbox{}
    \nomenclature{$R$}{Radius blade}
    \nomenclature{$C_p$}{Power coefficient}
    \nomenclature{$I_r$}{Third item}
    \printnomenclature
\end{framed}

c
c
c

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you use `makeindex` to compile your document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: leandriis I am using TeXworks and in the compilator I have pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX

Comment: When I use only makeIndex here is the message displayed :Couldn't find input index file elsarticle-template nor elsarticle-template.idx.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Comment: According to the documentation of `nomencl` you have to configure your makindex as follows: makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls

Comment: Where can I configure my makeindex because I am using TeXworks and I click on EDIT then PREFERENCES ==> TYPESETTINGS ===> MAKEINDEX ===> EDIT ==> there are  a name (MakeIndex)  program( miktex-makeindex.exe) and argument ($basename) So where I can type de input index ?

Comment: As I have no experience in working with TeXworks I can only recommend, that you have a look at the following question and its answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122811/134144

Comment: Yes I had a look on it before I post my problem here he used \immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls} but  nothing happens I still have no nomenclature

Comment: Alternatives could be a) executing the command directly from the command line or b) switching to a different editor like TeXMaker that can be configured more easily.

Comment: The problem is that I am used to work with TeXworks

Comment: \immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls} it works I was thinking that jobname is the filename while jobname is a command lol