# What can I do to print the nomenclature here?

Tags: nomencl

I previously used nomencl without issues, but I recently got this problem I cannot solve.

Below you can find a MWE. I use TeXworks. The first line comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154802/27256). Even after multiple runs of the "pdfLaTeX" command, no nomenclature is printed.
This is most baffling to me, because the same document had previously a nomenclature created in this way.
I cannot identify where it stopped showing, and the MWE that does not produce it, also does not contain any of the latest included packages of the original document, so I would exclude any possible conflict between packages.

MWE:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[english]{article}
% Packages
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\title{ \LARGE \bf title\\}
\makenomenclature
% Start Document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\printnomenclature
\nomenclature{foo}{a function}
\nomenclature{bar}{an argument}
\nomenclature[a]{fubar}{an undesired result}
\section{test}
\end{document}
% End Document
```

Result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Otherwise, what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I get the nomenclature correctly. You are probably not enabling shell escape. Compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>.tex`. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82710/134574).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik please turn that into an answer, so that I can accept it! Also, any idea why I was able to obtain a nomenclature without shell escape earlier?

Comment: I wrote an answer. As for the reason you had the nomenclature before, it's hard to say. You probably had a non-empty .nls file that was being read by your .tex file. You probably were testing the `makeindex` command line and generated the .nls file, then subsequent runs of `pdflatex` read that into the nomenclature section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nomencl` package uses `makeindex` to sort the entries alphabetically. To make the nomenclature work correctly you must run:

```
pdflatex - To write the \nomenclature commands into the .nlo file
makeindex - To read the .nlo file, sort it, and write the to the .nls file
pdflatex - To read back the .nls file and write the nomenclature to the .pdf
```

The command line to run `makeindex` is:

```
makeindex <file>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <file>.nls
```

where file is the name of your main .tex file.

It's quite a mouthful to write every time, that why you have that first line to your .tex file:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
```

which will run `makeindex` automatically every time.

You are not getting the nomenclature because `makeindex` was never called, so the .nls file is empty. You have to enable shell escaping to make any `\write18` work correctly.

You can run `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>.tex` by hand or, as you use TeXWorks, you can [enable `-shell-escape`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82710/134574) automatically.

---

Recommendation:

`-shell-escape` can be dangerous, if you copy code from the internet, you allow the code to do *anything* in your computer, so be careful. In general, this kind of thing doesn't happen, but better safe than sorry.

As an alternative you can use `arara` to automate this kind of thing. `arara` has a rule dedicated to the `nomencl` package. You can simply add this to the header of your document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
```

and compile with `arara <file>.tex`.