# nomenclature for thesis

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

Hello everybody I am using these packages in my preamle to print list of abbreviations:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
```

and
`\printnomenclature` where to print it.

and inside the document I used the

```
\nomenclature[2]{$\beta$}{The second letter of the greek alphabet}
```

but still it is not printed?

Comment: You need to run `makeindex` as well.

Comment: You may find useful information here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428276/134574

Comment: Is there any news here?